How does SSH make sure server side output not lost while client side consume slowly
I'm developing an application that consumes result of command ssh -p29418 xx@gerrit.host gerrit stream-events -s comment-added.
This command output events as json, one event per line.
{"type":"comment-added",change:{"project":"tools/gerrit", ...}, ...}


Here's an example code of my application.
// A ssh client library
Jsch client = new JSch();
Session session = client.getSession("username", "host", 22);
session.setPassword("password");
session.connect();

ChannelExec channelExec = (ChannelExec) session.openChannel("channelExec");
channelExec.setCommand("gerrit stream-events -s comment-added");
channelExec.connect();

InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(channelExec.getInputStream());
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);

String event;
while ((event = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    handleEvent(event);
}

As a constract, i started two instance of this application (first instance handleEvent method return in 1s, second instance handleEvent return in 20s). Imaging that after a long time running, the first instance recorded all events sent by server, but the second instance lost event randomly, is this possible?


What will happen to the event producer when consumer consume events (the second app) slower than producer (gerrit stream-events)?
I've read some pages explaining that the socket sender cannot continue send bytes until the socket receiver's recv_buf has enough spaces. Does this limitation will block process output message to stdout?
What's the difference between socket write_buf and java program System.out's write_buf? What will happen if java program stdout be redirected to socket output but sender write_buf and receiver recv_buf  is full?
How does ssh server-side redirect stdout of command gerrit stream-events and deliver to client-side.



It stalls. 2. No. , unless stdout is a socket. 3. System.out doesn’t have a member called write_buf. 4. With pipe(2).


And note that all this rate-limiting and stalling is performed by TCP, not by SSH.

Thanks for your professional answer @user207421, your answer makes me more curious about stdout and the pipe which redirect it to socket output. Assume that i start a java process with command "ssh user@somehost java test.jar", and the java process keeps print messages to stdout using System.out, and i read those messages line by line at a slow rate, what will happen to the java process?  Will the process keeps printing messages using System.out without stalling? If without stalling, where does messages that cannot be handled fastly be stored?

No. As System.out is a pipe(2) in this case, it will stall. All that data can't just go nowhere.
